# Virtual machine of a real installed system

Tags: boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine, multi-boot, virtualization

I have a dual boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 19.04. **Is it possible to setup a VM (or equivalent) of my Ubuntu system when Windows is booted ?** The question could also work the other way, a VM of the Windows system when under Ubuntu.

EDIT : the main idea is to read/write the files on the real file system on the real partition and not copy it over to a vm hard disk which is not always possible

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I'm sure I have posted a lenghty writeup on how to do this a few months ago, but I can't find it right now...

Comment: I've found it, [here you go](https://superuser.com/a/1434581/194694). This is not 100% identical as in this question OP doesn't want to boot from bare metal. It's possible though, you just need to add GRUB with proper config to ESP. It won't be trivial and will require knowledge of Linux boot process and UEFI boot setup in general. It's doable though, [I had it working](https://superuser.com/q/545303/194694).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a VM image from a running Windows PC and run it in VirtualBox on Ubuntu. [Reference](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/convert-use-your-physical-machine-in-vmware-virtualbox-virtual-pc/)

Comment: OP wants to still have all data on an actual partition, not disk image file.

Comment: Like Bootcamp on OSX?

Comment: Bootcamp doesn't use a VM, it's a regular dual boot where you have either macOS or Windows.

Comment: Would a small system image that mounts the disk suffice?