# Converting a physical machine to a bootable Hyper-V VM

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, disk2vhd

I'm trying to convert a physical machine to become a Hyper-V VM. I've used Disk2VHD to create .vdhx images of the required drives.

[image]

What I'm struggling with is how I should create a Hyper-V image so that it will be a **bootable** VM based on the hard drive images.

I would have thought that I can choose the image of the C:\ drive as per screenshot below, but I guess that is wrong as it is not booting up.
What options should I select when creating a Hyper-V VM so that it will boot with the same OS as the physical machine?

Any assistance will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you created the VM as Generation 1?

Comment: No, a Generation 2.

Comment: This won't work with Windows below version 8. Generation 1 is required.

Comment: In addition, if you have the option to leave the hard drive plugged in, you can just use it for the VM. This will increase the speed of the VM while also being less trouble setting it up.

Comment: Thanks. I now selected Gen 1. But when I select my old C:\ drive as a VHD, I get an error "missing operating system" when I start. Selecting the 1st "\\?\\Volume" drive goes into a repairing hard drive mode and then just say it can't be repaired after about 30 mins. So should I select my old c:\ drive or \\?\\Volume drive?

Comment: I have not tried this myself yet, but maybe following these instructions will get you there: https://superuser.com/questions/1284201/hyper-v-boot-to-os-on-physical-disk

Comment: Thanks. Had a look at the link but does not seem to be the same scenario as what I have.

Comment: As an alternative, you can try using StarWind V2V converter. It allows doing a P2V directly to a VM. 
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/ConvertPhysicalMachinetoremoteMicrosoftHyperVServer.html

Comment: Starwindsoftware did do the trick, thanks.